# rsync .git directory

Tags: git, rsync

*This question probably is based on my lack of understanding of the role of .gits and git repositories in general but:*

Can I rsync a dir with content that I created with `git init` between machines ?

I have a repository on my laptop, and the only way to get it away from there is scp/rsync to a remote host, from which I can download it again. Could I rsync the complete directory structure between these hosts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. IIRC, git uses a relative approach. So it's safe to sync it with another computer.

Comment: It is possible (with the caveat that filesystem-based remotes and alternates might not work) if you don't do any work on the repository during rsync.

Answer (score 33):

There are a few possibilities:

- You can just `rsync` the `.git` repository (or even whole repository together with working directory), provided that you don't have any activity in repository during `rsync`ing (same disclaimer as for using `rsync://` protocol).
- <s>You can clone or fetch using *deprecated* `rsync` protocol (where repository URL / location looks like this: "`rsync://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/`").  Note that this protocol is deprecated, because if there is any activity in repository, you can get corrupted clone (or fetch).</s>

  <s>Also, as I have heard, it didn't work correctly in the presence of packed refs since 2007, and nobody noticed till recently.</s> It will (it did) disappear in Git 2.8.
- Or you can create [git bundle](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html), `rsync` it or `scp` it on other machine, and then clone or fetch from bundle.

Comment: As I note [in my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1398041/6309), git `rsync://` protocol will *finally* disappear in git 2.8 only (March 2016, 10+ after starting being declared as "deprecated"!)

Comment: This no longer works - gives the error `git-over-rsync is no longer supported`

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can, but you should do so with a bare repository, as illustrated in [this 2012 article](https://web-archive-org.translate.goog/web/20121013083044/http://xhtml.net/articles/git-deploiement-application-web?_x_tr_sl=fr&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp):

```
$ git clone --bare ./projet projet.git
$ rsync -a --stats --delete ./projet.git/ votre.serveur:~/projets/projet.git/
```

---

Note: 6+ years later, git 2.8 (March 2016) will officially **deprecate and fully remove the git rsync protocol**!

See [commit 0d0bac6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d0bac67ce3b3f2301702573f6acc100798d7edd) (30 Jan 2016) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9f03176](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f03176ef679ea5e0fb9088529180db72ae0764b), 17 Feb 2016)</sup>

> It turns out "`git clone`" over rsync transport has been broken when
> the source repository has packed references for a long time, and
> nobody noticed nor complained about it.

[Commit 0d0bac6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d0bac67ce3b3f2301702573f6acc100798d7edd) from [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff) has all the details.

Comment: Bare repository is only needed when you want to push to that repo. Bit if you just copy the repo each time, you can just do it with a full repo.

Comment: You can use rsync for full repository as well. There is nothing special about bare repository if you use rsync.

Comment: @Ikke: true, I usually do that kind of operation with the intent of pushing to it.

Answer (score 6):

You can rsync without any problems, but if you have some remotes declared with hostnames which are local to the machine (i.e. stored in /etc/hosts only) then those obviously won't work.

However, is there some reason why you don't use git itself to sync the content?

Comment: I was figuring that as my remote server doesnt have git I couldnt git push to it

Comment: True, if you want to use push via SSH, then you have to have git on server too (but you can have it installed locally, and use `--receive-pack` option to `git-push`, and similar option for fetch/pull/clone).  If you want to push via HTTP, you need to have only web server with WebDAV, configured to allow push access for you (no git on server required).

Comment: git clone is hanging for me and I can't find a solution on the web so rsync would help my cause but I too don't understand if some contents of `.git` are host-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `rsync`ing the `.git` dir is possible and will result in a complete clone of the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Using rsync to backup .git is possible, but with one catch ( at least to myself)
It can not be updated. The next time you try to rsync it again, you got massive object rename.. and you can not delete those.. 
Been not familiar with rsync or linux system, I purge the .git backup before I rsync it.

Which is:

```
> chmod -R 777 /path/of/your/backup/.git
> rm -fr /path/of/your/backup/.git
> rsync /path/of/your/origin/.git /path/of/your/backup/.git
```

I know, this is very taxing and stupid.. Please let me know is there a better way to do this..

Comment: ya if your trees in `.git` are the slightest bit different it will add a lot of data.

Comment: From `man rsync`: `--delete                delete extraneous files from dest dirs`. That will delete Git's old object files (and anything else that has been deleted from the source) from the backup. You may also want `--recursive`.