# Large Git -repo sync with Rsync, wget and Git -- or some ready tool?

Tags: git, wget, rsync

My friend wants to store electrically her school -notes and process them fast, with backups. She has over 2GB -size repo already and growing all the time (mostly appended material i.e. more school notes, different formats, pdf, pictures and scanned, some text -files, etc). The goal of my friend is to process fast the notes. I suggested command like this [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/901/download-an-entire-website) i.e. `"# crontab -e  @weekly wget --random-wait -e robots=off -U mozilla -mirror http://VeryLong.com"`. But I think plugging in Rsync somewhere could make it much better with Git, not getting weekly dupes i.e. trying to keep the size reasonable.

**Helper questions**

> 1. How should I use Rsync with Git here? Do I need wget at all?
> 2. Some command like `"ssh port:herWebSite.com:port"-and-then-directing-to-localhost/etc can mean privacy -peace but complicate things, solve this problem somehow
>      at the same time easily? I am thinking to propose her to store her notes only accessable with a SSH-priv-key, still thinking how I should help her with this not to overcomplicate things.
> 3. How would you help my friend to process and store the school -material under Git-version-controlling and still keep the size reasonable?

**Perhaps related**

> 1. [rsync .git directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398018/rsync-git-directory)
> 2. [rsync git big repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167442/rsync-git-big-repository)
>
> **Different scope**
>
> 3. [Git/rsync mix for projects with large binaries and text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281678/git-rsync-mix-for-projects-with-large-binaries-and-text-files)
> 4. [What's a good way to organize a large collection of personal scripts using git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657899/whats-a-good-way-to-organize-a-large-collection-of-personal-scripts-using-git)

Comment: I don't think Git introduces a lot of overhead for binary files, so what's the problem? Also, is `git clone` via SSH too slow? That's the first thing I would try

Comment: @NiklasB. `Process` implies changes. If the materials such as pictures, scanned -materials and PDFs change -- overhead, bad. She wants thing to be automatic which creates new challenges, a lot of small details to look at. It took 2 hours to download the whole directory with wget (yes she uses a content-host to browse her notes from any computer). I want to make sure the command does not kill her content-host because wgetting increasing repo of over 2GB may create soon too much traffic.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to look into `git-annex assistant`:

- http://git-annex.branchable.com/assistant/
- http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/joeyh/git-annex-assistant-like-dropbox-but-with-your-own

Might not be ready for Windows/Mac, but looks like it just went beta for Linux today.

Comment: What is the graphical frontend?

Comment: The graphical frontend is a local-running webapp.  Uses the current user's default web browser.